Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface even when the entity is annotated with jakarta.persistence.Entity
I'm trying to enable LoadTimeWeaving in spring boot project.
What I've done so far:

Added @EnableLoadTimeWeaving annotation
Added vm options when running the application (-javaagent:path/to/spring-instrument.jar)

Upon starting the application I'm getting the following error:
13:27:55.492 [main] INFO  o.s.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport - Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.something.SomethingRepository; If you want this repository to be a JPA repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: jakarta.persistence.Entity, jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository


Notes:

Annotated my entity with @jakarta.persistence.Entity
I am extending org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository here. It seems to work if I use JpaRepository instead. However, I would like to know the root cause of this. Shouldn't annotating the entity with @Entity be enough as stated in the error? I think I'm missing something here.

Observations:

org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension#getIdentifyingAnnotations gets Entity.class, and MappedSuperClass.class from class loader ClassLoaders.AppClassLoader.

@Override
    protected Collection<Class<? extends Annotation>> getIdentifyingAnnotations() {
        return Arrays.asList(Entity.class, MappedSuperclass.class);
    }


This is then compared with the @Entity annotation from my entity to see if they are the same by org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotations#isMappingForType method. But they are not equal probably because of different class loader. More on this in #3

    private static boolean isMappingForType(AnnotationTypeMapping mapping,
            AnnotationFilter annotationFilter, @Nullable Object requiredType) {

        Class<? extends Annotation> actualType = mapping.getAnnotationType();
        return (!annotationFilter.matches(actualType) &&
                (requiredType == null || actualType == requiredType || actualType.getName().equals(requiredType)));
    }


When getting the class loader to get the repository interfaces org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension#getConfigurationInspectionClassLoader method is invoked which returns InspectionClassLoader as LazyJvmAgent.isActive(loader.getClassLoader()) returns true.

    @Override
    protected ClassLoader getConfigurationInspectionClassLoader(ResourceLoader loader) {

        ClassLoader classLoader = loader.getClassLoader();

        return classLoader != null && LazyJvmAgent.isActive(loader.getClassLoader())
                ? new InspectionClassLoader(loader.getClassLoader())
                : loader.getClassLoader();
    }

So my question is: What is it that I'm missing here? Shouldn't they use the same class loader if we need to check equality like that? I would change all CrudRepository to JpaRepository but  it might create some other issues  it kind of looks hackish to me as it should already work with @Entity annotation. Any insights on this?
Edit: Note: I have multiple data source in this project.

Shouldn't create any issues since you are using JPA, having JpaRepository instead of CrudRepository just gives you a lot more methods to work with the repository like saveAndFlush, deleteInBatch etc, nowdays it also extends ListCrudRepository so you also have findAll which returns List, etc...

I meant that the LTW/ spring-instrument agent might have created other issues that I'm unaware of. Updating CrudRepository to JPARepository will make my application start successfully. But it seems like a hack to me as my entity has the annotation (@Entity) it requires. TBH, I doubt that I'm setting this up correctly. Thanks!

AOP, especially in Spring, is a complex interplay of framework, platform, application and aspect code as well as configuration. To be able to say anything intelligent about your problem without having to create a project from scratch, filling in the many gaps your question left behind, I suggest you publish an MCVE on GitHub. Then, probably I or other community members shall have a spot-on, helpful answer for you.

Hi @kriegaex , I was trying to create an MCVE like you suggested and had been facing another issue. Anyway, I downgraded the JPA version to replicate this issue. Here is the MCVE on github. You'll need to run the bootRun task from build.gradle which attaches the spring-instrumentation.jar to the VM argument. Let me know if you have any questions regarding this. Thank you!

"APPLICATION FAILED TO START. Parameter 0 of constructor in com.mcve.ltw.controller.TestController required a bean of type 'com.mcve.ltw.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found. Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mcve.ltw.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration."

That is because It could not create a bean of UserRepository as it was annotated with CrudRepository. We have to annotate it with JpaRepository to successfully start the application and that is the initial issue. I'm going to add a screenshot of the log (problem in the question above). Thank you for looking into it

OK, you should have mentioned that the application exits with that error. I thought, this was another problem. I found the log message you mentioned further up now.

If you set a breakpoint somewhere in RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport::isStrictRepositoryCandidate, you see what happens there. If you use JPA, it expects a JPA repository. So far, so unsurprising. Is there any problem for you in extending JpaRepository?

I apologize for the confusion. I'm going to keep that in mind for my future MCVEs. I'm just worried that I'm setting this up incorrectly. Also, not changing all the occurrences of CrudRepository would have been ideal because the project I'm working on has a lot of them.

I am sure your IDE or code editor has global search & replace. IntelliJ IDEA even has structural s&r.

It does. Thanks for taking the time to look into this. I appreciate it so much. Btw, there's a workaround I've left on the comment, would appreciate your feedback there as well.

The problem is simply that spring-instrument is an agent which attaches another agent - namely aspectjweaver - later during runtime. Invesdwin does a similar thing, trying to avoid the java agent on the command line altogether.
The solution is to simply do it right and use -javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver-1.9.22.jar (the version used by your sample program) directly instead of spring-instrument. I tried with your sample, changing one line in your build.gradle as follows:
jvmArgs(["-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver-1.9.22.jar"])

It works beautifully. @Entity and CrudRepository are enough, just as you like it. The agent needs to be attached during the start of the JVM, then there are no classloader problems.
BTW, if you want to embed the AspectJ weaver or any other agent into an executable Spring Boot JAR and auto-start it from there without any extra command line arguments, take a look at Agent Embedder Maven Plugin. I am the maintainer, and no, I did not port it to Gradle.

Below is just a workaround that we may use if we can not update CrudRepository to JpaRepository.
Opinion: Since having an Entity should be "sufficient" to consider a repository a JPA repository. I think spring-data-jpa should have compared the Entity.class from the same class loader because they are checking the equality (reference) of jakarta.persistence.Entity.class and the one annotated on my entity.
Proposed Solution: The purpose of this is to enable LoadTimeWeaving. So, we should be able to weave a couple of org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension methods to use the same classloader regardless of any active agent.
Steps:
Creating an aspect to return the same class loader:

@Aspect
public class JpaRepositoryAspect {

    private InspectionClassLoader inspectionClassLoader;

    @Around("execution(* org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.getConfigurationInspectionClassLoader(..)) && args(loader,..)")
    public Object getConfigurationInspectionClassLoader(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, ResourceLoader loader) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = loader.getClassLoader();

        if (classLoader != null && LazyJvmAgent.isActive(classLoader)) {
            inspectionClassLoader = new InspectionClassLoader(classLoader);
            return inspectionClassLoader;
        }
        return classLoader;
    }

    @Around("execution(* org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.getIdentifyingAnnotations(..))")
    public Object getIdentifyingAnnotations(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        if (inspectionClassLoader != null) {
            List<Class<?>> classes = Arrays.asList(inspectionClassLoader.loadClass("jakarta.persistence.Entity"),
                    inspectionClassLoader.loadClass("jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass"));
            inspectionClassLoader = null; // Just setting it null to avoid unintended effects
            return classes;
        }
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}



Create helper class that is basically the copy of what JPA is doing because they're not public

    /**
     * This is the ditto implementation of {@link org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.InspectionClassLoader}.
     */
    private static class InspectionClassLoader extends ShadowingClassLoader {

        InspectionClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {

            super(parent, true);

            excludePackage("org.springframework.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the ditto implementation of {@link org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.LazyJvmAgent}.
     */
    private static class LazyJvmAgent {

        private static final Set<String> AGENT_CLASSES;

        static {

            Set<String> agentClasses = new LinkedHashSet<>();

            agentClasses.add("org.springframework.instrument.InstrumentationSavingAgent");
            agentClasses.add("org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JavaSECMPInitializerAgent");

            AGENT_CLASSES = Collections.unmodifiableSet(agentClasses);
        }

        private LazyJvmAgent() {}

        /**
         * Determine if any agent is active.
         *
         * @return {@literal true} if an agent is active.
         */
        static boolean isActive(@Nullable ClassLoader classLoader) {

            return AGENT_CLASSES.stream() 
                    .anyMatch(agentClass -> ClassUtils.isPresent(agentClass, classLoader));
        }
    }

I'm more than happy to get the feedbacks as I'm really new to this.
Here's the MCVE. Just checkout "weave-jpa-repository-config-extension" branch to see the changes.
Note: Had to use invesdwin-instrument to hot attach the agent because I've spent a lot of time on this already and I don't have to do it on the actual project I'm working on.
Thanks @krieagaex for taking your time to look into it. I really appreciate it.

This is an ugly hack and would need to be maintained by the colleagues who come after you. Bad idea.

I agree it's a pretty ugly hack, and I thought the same. I saw your answer too and that is the way to go. Thanks.
